# UWP background task for logging in/ logging out

Tags: uwp, background-task

I am trying to find a background task which will get triggered when the user signs out and signs back in. I looked into some of the SystemTrigger types and came across SessionsConnected trigger. My understanding is that this is a system trigger when a session ends and that means this would be triggered on a log out and log back in. Is there a different way to use this trigger for sign in and sign out? Or is there a different trigger to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there are no other UWP APIs that could directly detect the user logging in/logging out. I think the `SessionsConnected trigger` that you found does the work in some scenarios.

But if you want to have a separate event for both logging in and logging out actions, then you might need to use the [SystemEvents.SessionEnded Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionended?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) and [SystemEvents.SessionSwitch Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0). These are .Net APIs that need to be used in desktop apps. So you have to create a desktop app and package the desktop app together with the UWP app using desktop bridge.